# Why is "libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop" part of non-Unity flavors in 13.10?

Tags: lubuntu, scopes

**OS**: Lubuntu 13.10, clean install.

I noticed an update for `libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop`. To find out what that is, I ran `apt-cache show libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop` and saw this, in part:

```
[10:44 AM] ~ $ apt-cache show libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop
Package: libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Installed-Size: 52
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: libunity
Version: 7.1.2+13.10.20131010-0ubuntu2
...
...
Description-en: binding to get places into the launcher - desktop def file
 libunity is a shared library to be able to interact with the launcher
 and add places in Unity environment.
...
 This package contains default scopes definition for the destkop.
...
...
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb, xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Is the presence of this package in Lubuntu and other non-Unity flavors intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just `libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop`. There are other Unity-related packages as well. I looked at `/var/log/apt/history.log` and found:

```
gir1.2-unity-5.0                  GObject introspection data for the Unity library
libunity-protocol-private0        binding to get places into the launcher - private library
libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop  binding to get places into the launcher - desktop def file
libunity9                         binding to get places into the launcher - shared library
```

Looking at the output of`apt-cache showpkg libunity9`, for example, shows that several common, "cross-environment" packages such as `deja-dup`, `empathy`, `evolution`, `psensor`, and `thunderbird`,  carry `libunity9` as a dependency. And `libunity9` has some of the Unity packages listed above as dependencies.

In other words, having these Unity packages present in a non-Unity desktop is quite understandable.